# What can I do when I have forgotten my LastPass Master Password?

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-recovery, lastpass

Right, 
  Here's the situation I'm in - got assigned to a new system. Installed LastPass. LastPass login stares at me... and I'm blank.

The password hint doesn't work ( mainly because after their [recent anomaly](http://blog.lastpass.com/2011/05/lastpass-security-notification.html), I changed my master password but didn't update the password hint question). I'm logged in to my LastPass vault via my Nexus S, as well as my laptop at my home.

But how do I retrieve the master password from either of them? I don't have the master password saved in LastPass vault or in any of the the browser password managers. Neither do I have it written down somewhere

Comment: sticky situation your in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just revert your password to the last one like it's stated in the most recent blog entry on the site you provided? - Or am I missing something.

> Many users are changing their password and then determining they
>   can't remember it, a number have also
>   run into issues with password changes
>   and want to go back, you can now do
>   this yourself without contacting us:
>   https://lastpass.com/revert
>
> It allows you to either roll back your last password change or revert
>   your account to the 4th. You must
>   prove access to your email again to
>   use it.

Comment: Hmm, I missed that - I had the URL stored but didn't pay a visit to the post after the initial post - will try that out.

Comment: thanks, I used the link to revert to my old password, and changed the password again(!) with the updated hint :)

Answer (score 3):

According to [their site](http://helpdesk.lastpass.com/account-recovery/) there are 4 steps to follow:

> 1) Attempt to login through the LastPass website at https://lastpass.com/. If you are able to login via the website but not via the plugin, this is likely a problem with the LastPass browser add-on, in which case you should report the problem to us directly.
>
> 2) If you cannot login through the website, try the password hint that you setup for yourself when you created your LastPass account. The password hint is not your Master Password.
>
> 3) If the password hint doesn't help you, go to the account recovery page to activate your local One Time Password and recover your account. Follow the instructions there - if the first computer on which you attempt access doesn't work, try the same process on any other computer on which you have previously accessed your LastPass account.
>
> 4) If at this point you have failed to remember your password, your account hint didn't jog your memory, and you've tried the password recovery on every machine you've logged into, your only recourse is to delete your account and start over.

It looks like you've done the first two.  The third option somehow allows you to get a temp, local password.  If that doesn't work, the situation doesn't look good.

Comment: 3rd option - is something which I can try.

Answer (score 1):

LastPass doesn't store your master password anywhere, so there's no way to retrieve it from the service.  You probably need to reset it again.

Answer (score 1):

Usually people forget their password and number of issues comes from it. The Lastpass doesn't know your master password. you can try these steps:-

1. sign into Lastpass.com
2. Try your password hint that you have setup when you created your account
3. If the hint doesn't help, goto the account recovery page to active your one time password that allow you to change your master password if you have logged into Lastpass on any computer; and is the only way to reset your master password
4. if you can not able to recover your password, delete your account to start over, this action will remove your data but your Premium status will be transferred if you use the same email